# LNK 2019 "Unresolved External Symbol" Error (C++ OpenGL)

Tags: c++, opengl, linker-errors, glfw

I'm relatively new to C++ and I've been having some problems while making classes in files. I'm trying to call a constructor from a separate class, Shader, and use a method in said class. However whenever I try to build the solution, I get the following error:

```
Error   2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall Shader::Use(void)" (?Use@Shader@@QAEXXZ) referenced in function _main    
Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Shader::Shader(char const *,char const *)" (??0Shader@@QAE@PBD0@Z) referenced in function _main
```

I know that there is nothing wrong with the Project Properties Linker or the rendering system because I've rendered things before with my current configuration, so I figure it must have something to do with the code but I can't figure it out:

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

// GLEW
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL/glew.h>

// GLFW
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

// Other includes
#include "Shader.h"

int main ()
{

(... Window Setup ...)


// Build and compile shader program
Shader shaders ("shader.vs", "shader.frag");


(... Set up vertex data (and buffer(s)) and attribute pointers ...)

// Game loop
while(!glfwWindowShouldClose (window))
{
    glfwPollEvents ();

    ourShader.Use ();

(... Draw triangle ...)

    glfwSwapBuffers (window);
}
(... De-allocate all resources ...)

(... Terminate window ...)
return 0;
}
```

Shader.h

```
#ifndef SHADER_H
#define SHADER_H

#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

#include <GL/glew.h>

class Shader
{
public:

GLuint Program;
Shader(const GLchar* vertexPath, const GLchar* fragmentPath);
void Use ();

};

#endif
```

Shader.cpp

```
#ifndef SHADER_H
#define SHADER_H

#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

#include <GL/glew.h>

#include "Shader.h"

class Shader
{
public:
GLuint Program;
Shader::Shader(const GLchar* vertexPath, const GLchar* fragmentPath)
{
    (... 1. Retrieve the vertex/fragment source code from filePath ...)

    (... 2. Compile shaders ...)

    (... 3. Link shader program ...)

    (... 4. Delete shaders after usage ...)
}

void Shader::Use ()
{
    (... Use current shader program ...)
}
};

#endif
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. If any more code is needed I can provide. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you actually compiling Shader.cpp?

Comment: You should only define the class once, in the header. The definitions of the members go in the source file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, if this compiles it's because the inclusion guard in `shader.cpp` removes the erroneous code. Secondly, if you remove the inclusion guard from `shader.cpp` (which you should) this won't compile, because the class is declared twice in shader.cpp (via `#include "Shader.h"`). The linking error in turn occurs because main.cpp isn't being linked with a compiled version of shader.cpp.

1. Remove the inclusion guard from `shader.cpp` - since you define `SHADER_H` in `shader.h`, the preprocessor will remove all the code from `shader.cpp` before it hits the compiler
2. Remove the class declaration from shader.cpp, but keep the definitions of all members of the shader class. Just keep `shader.cpp` simple, like so:

   ```
   #include "shader.h"

   Shader::Shader(const GLchar* vertexPath, const GLchar* fragmentPath)
   { /*..body */ }

   Shader::use()
   { /*..body */ }
   ```
3. Make sure you link `main` with the compiled version of shader, e.g. `g++ main.cpp shader.o`, assuming shader was compiled separately, e.g. `g++ -c shader.cpp`

Comment: That did it. Thank you!